# How to send data from client to redis and then after to laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, node-redis

I'm using laravel and redis for real time chat. I can fire event from my laravel and receiving that data to client side.

My problem is how can i send something from client and then receive it to redis and pass it to laravel

E.g How can i check if user has read the chat message.

Code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require( 'socket.io' ).listen( server );
var redis = require('redis');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
server.listen(port,'x.x.x.x');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log("Connected");
});
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.psubscribe(['get_message','read_message']);
redisClient.on("pmessage", function(channel, pattern, message) {
    console.log(channel); // i can see get_message on this line in console but not read_message
});

//Also tried this
io.on('read_message', function (socket) {
   console.log(socket);
});
//Also this
redisClient.on('read_message', function (socket) {
   console.log(socket);
});

redisClient.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

Note : I'm emitting data from IOS app.

Comment: You should be using AJAX requests for asynchronous client to server updates

Comment: Did you read my note at the last?

Comment: Yes I did, why would you be unable to send requests to your server from your client?

Answer (score 5):

Redis is a key/value store engine.  You should treat it like a database.

A client sends a request to a webserver that receives this request and decides what to do with it.  For requests that require server-side processing, it will pass that request to a server-side "engine" for processing, in your case, probably PHP-FPM, which then passes it to a PHP daemon that will then execute the request.

Redis is not able to interpret a request in this manner.  Therefore, you must intercept the request with Laravel and then send it to Redis.  Not the other way around.

If you're trying to have Laravel get the information from Redis, you'll want to use [Redis' pub/sub feature](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).  Then you can have Laravel subscribe to Redis updates, get the updates and persist or handle the data however you want.

The [phpredis lib](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) supports the pub/sub functionality.

Here is an example of the PHP implementation with that lib.
https://xmeng.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/pubsub-in-redis-using-php/

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage Broadcasting in Laravel for the same. Also you can broadcast between multiple clients using whisper. Also there is a redis based broadcaster in it.

First you need to include its package in composer.

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"
```

Configure the credentials in app/broadcasting.php

```
'options' => [
'cluster' => 'eu',
'encrypted' => true
],
```

You need to configure broadcasting queue as well.

**Sending Broadcast**

```
event(new ShippingStatusUpdated($update)); //Broadcasts to everyone, avail to working scope as well
broadcast(new ShippingStatusUpdated($update));//Broadcasts only to others
```

**Receiving Broadcast**

Instantiate socket ID for echo [included in header as X-Socket-ID]

```
var socketId = Echo.socketId();
```

Make sure you have echo installed

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

Create echo instance

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key'
});
```

Listening events

```
Echo.channel('orders')
    .listen('OrderShipped', (e) => {
        console.log(e.order.name);
    });
```

Broadcast an event to other connected clients without hitting your Laravel application at all

```
Echo.channel('chat')
    .whisper('typing', {
        name: this.user.name
    });
```

[Laravel Broadcast Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting)

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial is what you want:

[Laravel 5 and Socket.io Tutorial](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-socket-io-tutorial/)

it contains tutorial for client side and server side

#### and for ios

you could use: [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

check this also: [Socket.IO on iOS](https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/#)